Parsing only macro calls using Lex and Yacc
I am trying to build a parser that will only parse C++ macro calls in a code-base and store the arguments in the macro calls for further processing. In that code-base, it is known that macros contain only upper case letters and underscores. I am using ply (Python lex and Yacc), which has fairly similar syntax as lex and yacc:
// token regexes:

VARIABLE_NAME := "[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+"
MACRO_NAME := "[A-Z\-]+"
COMMENTS := "(\/\/.*\n)|(\/\*.*\*\/)"
LPAREN := "\("
RPAREN := "\)"
COMMA := "\,"
SEMICOLON := "\;"
...

// parser rules

// list of arguments. It can be just a list of comma separated names
// or even contain other macro calls: MACRO_ONE(SomeVariable, MACRO_TWO(OtherVariable)

arg_list := VARIABLE COMMA arg_list
            | VARIABLE COMMA macro_calls
            | VARIABLE


macro_calls := MACRO_NAME LPAREN arg_list RPAREN

statement := macro_calls SEMICOLON
            | COMMENTS


Except macro calls, I want to ignore, any other statements. But when I try to use these rules, it gives syntax errors for undeclared symbols, like datatypes int, float etc.
Can someone please help me understand how to develop this parser so that I can process only the macro calls and ignore everything else?

What you are trying to do is not trivial. The parser expressions don't really cover how macros expand. Note: the gcc and g++ compiler will parse and do this expansion for you. Use the -E flag.

I don't know about ply, but lex has states, so normal_code (everything before MACRO_NAME) should be ignored, and you should tokenize only MACRO_NAME( .. ) (so count '(' and ')' to reset state to normal code).

Your comment token is also wrong /*1*/ .. /*2*/ would be considered by an unique comment, instead of 2 (with possible code between them).

@LokiAstari I do not want to expand the macros. I just want to match the macro calls and store the arguments in some way.

@Jarod42 thank you for the reply. But how can normal code be ignored? It us giving syntax error. Also, what is a correct comment regex ?

Regex for cpp comment is \/\*(?s:.)*?\*\/

I don't know about ply, but lex has states, so normal_code (everything before MACRO_NAME) should be ignored, and you should tokenize only MACRO_NAME( .. ) (so count '(' and ')' to reset state to normal code)
Here is a simplified version tested with https://mingodad.github.io/parsertl-playground/playground/
/*Tokens*/

%token VARIABLE
%token MACRO
%token LPAREN
%token RPAREN
%token COMMA

%start statements

%%

statements : macro_calls statements
            | 
            ;

arg_list : VARIABLE COMMA arg_list
          | VARIABLE COMMA macro_calls
          | VARIABLE
          |
          ;

macro_calls : MACRO LPAREN arg_list RPAREN
            ;

%%

%x MACRO_CALL

VARIABLE_NAME [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9\_]*
MACRO_NAME [A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*
COMMENTS [/][/].*|[/][*].*?[*][/]
LPAREN \(
RPAREN \)
COMMA ,
SPACE [ \n]

%%

<INITIAL>{SPACE} skip()
<INITIAL>{COMMENTS} skip()
<INITIAL>{MACRO_NAME}<MACRO_CALL> MACRO
<INITIAL>. skip()

<MACRO_CALL>{SPACE} skip()
<MACRO_CALL>{COMMENTS} skip()
<MACRO_CALL>{LPAREN} LPAREN
<MACRO_CALL>{VARIABLE_NAME} VARIABLE
<MACRO_CALL>{COMMA} COMMA
<MACRO_CALL>{RPAREN}<INITIAL> RPAREN

%%



numbers/strings not supported
balancing '(' ')' to reset to INITIAL state not done (so MACRO in MACRO won't work)
probably other stuff

but you might have the idea to complete fix the stuff you need now.
